# jQuery Fallback to Creating DOM Object If Search Is Empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just found a weird case that resulted in XSS, but I don't really understand why. The code in question was searching for a  tag with a matching name like this:

```
var varName = getCookie('cookiename');
var link = $('.someclass a[name=' + varName + ']');
```

If that cookie happens to contain XSS, executing that jQuery code results in the XSS being executed. I understand that on its own, something like $('< img src=x onerror=alert(1) />') will be added to the DOM and executed, based on what I read in the documentation. I don't get why the code above, with that same img tag as the variable value, has the same result. Shouldn't it just result in an empty variable?

Comment: What version of jQuery? Previous versions resulted in the above code creating an element instead of returning an empty array with invalid input. More recent versions instead throw an error  in that case. This is in fact the case with the version of jQuery stackoverflow currently uses.

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of jQuery, the following jquery selector would result in a div being created:

```
$('.someclass a[name=' + '<div>Hello World!</div>' + ']')
```

however, in more recent versions of jQuery, jQuery will not create a dom fragment unless the html string starts with a `<` which completely avoids this issue.

So, either validate the input before putting it in the selector, or update jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/g33n57vs/